# Joke about a magical tractor, I dont get it

Tags: jokes

The joke is:

> Did you hear about the magic tractor? It turned into a field.

What is the joke about?
I am thinking that the tractor is abandoned and the field cover it, I cant imagine other situation.

Help me please.

Thank you in advance.

PS: I am a native spanish speaker.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The joke is using two different meanings of "turned into." The first is that the tractor drove off of the road and turned a corner into a field - a common activity for a tractor to do. "The car turned into the driveway," "I turned left into Main Street," etc.

The second is saying that since this was a magical tractor, actually it physically turned/transformed into a field. "The magician turned his hat into a rabbit," "The caterpillar turned into a butterfly."

(Check the different meanings here: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+into )

Comment: Compare "Call me a taxi" - "You're a taxi".

Comment: I wonder if it should be ***magical*** *tractor* or ***magic*** *tractor*? I could make a case for each. I notice that you changed the word in your answer.